# What are conditions I can check for detecting error in downloading using bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to continuously download a link until it successfully downloads,

```
     #!/bin/bash 
     while [ some_condition  ]; do
         curl my_url
         # or
         vagrant add my_vagrant_url --name localdev --force
     done
```

What is correct way of detecting if download stream is not abnormally disconnected.

Comment: What do you realy mean with "downloads"?

Comment: See the documentation for `curl` or `vagrant` to see what exit status they return on an abnormal disconnect.  Then inspect the `$?` variable after running the commands to determine if they failed for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

`while ! curl my_url; do sleep 0.1; done`

curl supposedly exits with a nonzero exit code if there was an error.

The important thing to understand is that in shell, conditions of the form `[ ... ]` are not a special language construct. `[` is a command, and the rest up to and including the `]` are its arguments. Instead of the `[` command, you can use any command, because every command has an exit status, and the condition will evaluate to true if that exit status is zero.